# Table with thead and left most column fixed and scrolls outside the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to build a table that has the thead and the left-most column fixed, and at the bottom and the right of the outtermost container, I need scroll bars to scroll everything except the thead and the left most column.

Here we have a similar example that I found in stackoverflow
http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/81/

but as you can see the horizontal scroll appers only at the very bottom of the right column. I need to scroll all way down to see the scroll.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  function getRows(rows, cols) {
    var rowString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      rowString += "<tr>";
      for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        rowString += "<td>" + j + "," + i + "</td>";
      }
      rowString += "</tr>";
    }
    return rowString;
  }

  $("#left_table").append(getRows(2, 10));
  $("#inner_table").append(getRows(8, 10));
});
```

```css
.tblTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#vertical_scrolling_div {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  padding-top: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#freeze_container {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
}
#horizontal_scrolling_div {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.freeze_table {
  background-color: #0099dd;
  z-index: 2;
}
#left_table {
  width: 100px;
}
#inner_table {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vertical_scrolling_div">
  <div id="freeze_container">
    <table id="left_table" class="freeze_table">
      <tr class='tblTitle'>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="horizontal_scrolling_div">
    <table id="inner_table">
      <tr class='tblTitle'>
        <th>Title 3</th>
        <th>Title 4</th>
        <th>Title 5</th>
        <th>Title 6</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make that scroll appers always as the vertical one but scrolling horizontally only the right column?